# .NET 2.0 - Tokenizing space separated text

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, text-parsing

Suppose you have output like this:

```
Word1           Word2   Word3      Word4
```

Where the number of spaces between words is arbitrary. I want to break it into an array of words.

I used the following code:

```
string[] tokens =
         new List<String>(input.Split(' '))
             .FindAll
             (
                 delegate(string token)
                 {
                      return token != String.Empty;
                 }
             ).ToArray();
```

Not exactly efficient, but does the job nicely.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He already mentions string.Split().  What he's missing is StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries:

```
string[] tokens = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Genius. I didn't notice that overload.

Comment: You have to admit, anonymous delegates make it look cooler =)

Comment: Cooler, yes, more legible and obvious ... not so much. I never noticed this overload either, but it absolutely rocks! +1!

Comment: The best part is that it's easy to include tabs, newlines, and other whitespace in the array if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex for the split with "\w+" for the pattern.

Comment: See, that's why I'm afraid of regex.